# Updating new document.body.offsetHeight in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a piece of code which upon reaching the end of the page must load more data as such :

```
    React.useEffect(() => {

        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

            if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight && state.more == false) {
                getAscii(state.page, 21, dispatch)
                console.log("you're at the bottom of the page", state.page)
            }
        })
    }, [state])
```

However as I load more data I need `document.body.offsetHeight` to increase in size.

How can I get the new `document.body.offsetHeight` and update my condition ?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)

handleScroll = () => {
    const windowHeight =
        'innerHeight' in window
            ? window.innerHeight
            : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
    const body = document.body;
    const html = document.documentElement;
    const docHeight = Math.max(
        body.scrollHeight,
        body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight,
        html.scrollHeight,
        html.offsetHeight
    );

    const windowBottom = Math.round(windowHeight + window.pageYOffset);
    if (windowBottom >= docHeight && !this.state.loading) {
        this.setState({
            loading: true,
        });
     //Your logic to load more data
     }
```